# How to pass the raw data in body in while API calling using Retrofit

Tags: android

I have to pass the raw data in API calling using Retrofit.

The raw data to pass is as below :

```
{
  "data":{
    "vender_name": "manthan",
        "vender_address": "surndranagar",
        "vender_number": "9645837630",
        "vender_whatsapp_number": "9537386566",
        "vender_password": "test@123",
        "vender_city": "surndranagar",
        "vender_state": "Gujarat"
}
```

}

I have created a POJO class.

```
@POST("foo")
    Call<POJO class> obj(@Body POJO class pojo);
```

The execution is going in onFailure method,
I have to pass the raw data in body.
The row data is as below :

```
{
  "data":{
        "vender_name": "name",
        "vender_address": "address",
        "vender_number": "9898989898",
        "vender_whatsapp_number": "9898989898",
        "vender_password": "test@123",
        "vender_city": "city",
        "vender_state": "state"
}
}
```

Comment: please explain better, you want to send a request with a body in retrofit?

Comment: yes, I want to send a raw data in body, the API is POST.

Answer (score 0):

create a class model

```
public class DataModel {

    @SerializedName("word")
    private String word;

    public SearchModel(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

add class mode as a body in retrofit interface

```
@POST("api/data")
Call<ResponseModel> sentData(@Body DataModel data);
```

final step implement interface with base retrofit class